# How to track down how fiddler's auto responder works?

Tags: windbg, fiddler, http-proxy

Which win32 API should I set bp on to investigate how it does `http proxy`?

**UPDATE**

How does fiddler manage to capture all http requests of all processes?

I know it has a built-in http proxy server,but how does it make all processes use its http proxy?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See this for [How to programmatically query and set proxy settings under Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=226473)

I would guess that it uses `[GetTcpTable2][2]` and looks up the entries for the connection in the table.

Comment: can you elaborate how to use `GetTcpTable2` to do the job?

Comment: First use `getpeername` and `getsockname` on the incoming connection to get the local / remote ports.   Look for a row in the table with local and remote addresses that are loopback and ports that match the ones you got for the connection.  You should see two matching entries, one will have the PID of you proxy and the other the PID of the other process.

Comment: but how can I make other processes use my proxy programatically?

Comment: Fiddler does not "make" other processes use it.  These processes just use Internet Explorer's configuration.

Comment: then what do you mention `GetTcpTable2` and `getpeername ` for?

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler's website has tons of information about how it works. Fiddler doesn't just "have" a HTTP proxy, it *is* a HTTP proxy with a bit of UI sprinkled on top. Applications use Fiddler because they pick up the WinINET/System Proxy settings, which Fiddler sets when it attaches and unsets when it detaches. The proper API for that is InternetSetOption, passing in a null handle and a structure that points at Fiddler's listening TCP/IP port (127.0.0.1).

Fiddler only uses the IPHelper APIs in order to map inbound connections back to their originating process ID, which is used for the "Process" column in the UI.